# Glimpse installed, configured, and enabled, but not showing up

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I just installed **Glimpse.Mvc3** from **NuGet**. The package enabled trace and glimpse in my `web.config`. I can successfully get to `localhost/.../Glimpse/Config` (so no 404) and it reports that my **IP** is `127.0.0.1` and matches the allowed list. Clicking the On button shows my `glimpseState = On` (and I verified that the cookie is set). But when I go back and refresh my project, I see nothing new. Is there something else I need to be doing?

- GlimpseMvc3.0.82 from NuGet (Glimpse.Mvc3.dll reports v0.80 and Glimpse.Core.dll reports v0.83)
- Windows 7 SP1
- IIS 7.5
- .NET 4.0
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- MVC3 project with razor view engine
- Project is set to use local IIS in a virtual directory

My end goal here is to figure out why my site is a little sluggish, taking at least a full second every page. In webforms days, I would have otherwise just set Page.`Trace=True` and gotten a nice timestamped log, but such is not an option in **MVC**. Glimpse seems like it will fill that role and more.

**Edit:** I just opened my javascript error console and see that it is having issues loading `localhost/.../Glimpse/glimpseClient.js` and when I try to go there directly, I instantly get a very broken link. By that I mean it's not a 404, it acts like the server doesn't exist at all (a browser-specific page). Swapping `"glimpseClient.js"` for `"Config"` brings up the proper page, so the server address seems fine.

**Edit2:** I see an [open issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/66) on the project's github that sounds similar. Looking at the HTML source of my site, I see a bunch of glimpse code added at the bottom. glimpsePath is properly set to my virtual directory. My `web.config` already had `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the developers on glimpse and this issue is known and has just been resolved... please see http://blog.getglimpse.com/2011/06/21/404-errors-fixed-goodbye-glimpseconfig-hello-glimpse-axd/.

This is a known issue for a small percentage of users and if you read the post it goes pretty indepth about how and why this occurred. The fix will be in release 0.83+ which should be coming out within the week.

Sorry about any inconvenience.

Comment: I had skimmed through that, and thought it didn't apply, since I could get to /Glimpse/Config just fine and had runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" set in web.config. I don't need this right now, so I can wait a few weeks for release, but if you want a test case, I'm willing to pull source and test from there.

Comment: There are a few different scenarios and I'm thinking yours falls under the "Problem 2" section. In any case, if you are happy to test, give us a day or 2 more and we will have a private Alpha build for you to test. I will keep you posted. Thanks again for the report and feedback!

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded and included the update this morning and it definitely does fix the problem and the icon shows up and functions. I am seeing another problem on one page where, with Glimpse On, the page never finishes loading and eventually crashes the browser (repeated in Opera, Chrome, and IE9). Glimpse Off, the page loads fine. I'm new to SO, but I'm guessing this post isn't the best place to discuss the separate issue. How would you prefer to handle it, assuming you are interested?

Comment: Any chance you are using lazy loading in your view models? For this one switch over to https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues and report it. Also when you report it can you give us the glimpse logs. Meaning, in your config set loggingEnabled="true" on the glimpse element - hence it should look like <glimpse enabled="true" loggingEnabled="true">...</glimpse>. This will produce a log file called Glimpse.log. Once you have this, if you can include the output in the report you file that would be good.

Comment: I think all my pages are using lazy loading. I narrowed it down to one mundane LINQ2EF4.1 query and it works fine when I take it out, but I haven't been able to reproduce the problem in a simple new project. Once I do, I'll report the issue over on github. Thanks a lot for your help and the excellent library.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you were right again. I'm using lazy loading all over the back end, but this is the only page it's in the view model. [link](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/75) I shouldn't be binding my view to my model like that anyway, so I put the handful of needed properties in the separate view model and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to your page there should be a slightly transparent icon of an eye on the lower right corner. Click on the icon to bring up glimpse

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for, but nothing is there. I think the problem is with an inability to load a JS file. I edited the original post with the detail.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, it looked like the glimpse bar was not showing up at all, but I located it under my bottom floating footer.
I added `.glimpse-nowrap {bottom:52px;}` to a style tag in my _Layout.cshtml file, and was able to see and use the glimpse bar effectively.